# Does the compiler deal with this logical operation as a function?

Tags: c

I wondered when I use this code, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int b;
    scanf("%d",&b);
    if (b)
        printf("right\n");
    else
        printf("zero entered\n");
    return 0;
}
```

How can the compiler know that if `b!= 0`, it should execute `printf("right\n");`.....and if `b == 0` it should execute `printf("zero entered\n");`

And if I had another variable `a`, and check if `a > b` or not, the return from the logical operations is `1` or `0`; how this value is obtained?  Is it a function?

Comment: May be they are using C Language Specifications...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the compiler deals with this is to translate it into the appropriate machine instructions.

In the case of this:

```
if (b)
```

then this is typically, on an x86 machine, translated to something like this:

```
cmp eax, eax ; compare register eax with itself
jz  target   ; jump to target if zero
```

The above code tells you that zero is a special case in the cpu, in that many, if not most, of the instructions will set some internal flags when they operate on values, so that `jz` and `jnz` (jump if not zero) can be done afterwards.

There are other flags as well, overflow, carry, sign, parity.

As for comparison, for types that can be handled natively by the cpu, there are built in instructions:

```
mov eax, a  ; eax = a
cmp eax, b  ; compare eax to b
jl  target  ; jump to target if less (eax < b --> a < b)
```

You can find more of the jump instructions here: [Intel x86 JUMP quick reference](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html).

If the types cannot be handled natively, typically it will involve a function call, which returns a 0/1 (or 0/N, note that N can be negative) value, in which case it falls back to the `if (b)` type of instructions to handle the results of that function.

Something like this:

```
mov  eax, a    ; eax = a
mov  ebx, b    ; ebx = b
call function  ; call comparison function, result returned in eax
cmp  eax, eax
jz   notequal
```

Comment: + this is what I was suggested by [Jonathan Leffler](http://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler).

Comment: Just a precision, in C tradition comparison functions typically return negative/zero/positive rather than nonzero/zero.

Comment: negative/positive is nonzero.

Answer (score 4):

In C, all non-zero values are "true", and only zero is "false".

As for the comparison `a > b`, depending on the types there are instructions in the CPU running your program that does comparisons, and the compiler generates those instructions when compiling your program. For types that don't have a native comparison-instruction, it's up to the implementation of the compiler how those should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the value is true or false, you should always compare with zero because all integers are true except zero.